# Cards Probability and Combination

Tags: probability

Three cards are drawn at random(without replacement) from an ordinary deck of 52 cards. Find the number of ways in which one can draw 
a. A diamond and a club and a heart in succession
b. Two hearts and then a club or spade

Comment: a) The first can be any of $13$ cards. For each choice of first card, there are $13$ choices for second card (and so on). b) This first can be any of $13$ cards. For each choice of first card, there are $12$ choices for second card. And for each choice of first and second, there are $13$ choices for the third card. And so on.

Comment: @ André Nicolas So this will be the equation i guess, for a, 13X13X13. For b, 13X12X13. Am i right? I'm kinda confused. Sorry.

Comment: For b) it is $(13)(12)(13)(13)$. You have a) right.

Comment: You are welcome.